# Many to many as in code first approach in existing SQL Server New

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In code first approach, it would look like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
}

public class Package
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

It would automatically create junction table, and I could easily access `item1.Packages` or `package1.Items`. But I have trouble creating these tables in an existing SQL Server database. I am including this database into my project as new ADO.NET item, it then looks like `.edmx`

How do I make foreign keys in SQL query so relationships between tables would look like described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the tables as per the code-first classes you posted:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title NVARCHAR(MAX),
)

CREATE TABLE Packages
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title NVARCHAR(MAX),
)

CREATE TABLE ItemPackages
(
    ItemId INT NOT NULL,
    PackageId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES Items(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (PackageId) REFERENCES Packages(Id)
)
```